# Cordova - How to access Device Storage?

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, cordova

I am developping an cordova application that contain a MP3 Player, for that, I have to get all MP3 files in the device, I know how to search in the SDCard (with cordova.file.externalRootDirectory) but, how to access to the classic Device Storage? (Where there is "Android", "DCIM", "Download"... folders)

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The cordova.file.dataDirectory doesn't works

Answer (score 0):

I'm using plugin `cordova-plugin-file` and it works for me to access to internal file storage

```
var folderpath = cordova.file.dataDirectory + "Download/";
```

**Android directory structure**

- files: The application's internal file storage directory
- files-external: The application's external file storage directory
- sdcard: The global external file storage directory (this is the root of the SD card, if one is installed). You must have the android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to use this.
- cache: The application's internal cache directory
- cache-external: The application's external cache directory
- assets: The application's bundle (read-only)
- root: The entire device filesystem
- applicationDirectory: ReadOnly with restricted access. Copying files in this directory is possible, but reading it directly results in 'file not found'. Android also supports a special filesystem named "documents", which represents a "/Documents/" subdirectory within the "files" filesystem.

More information in [Apache doc](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/)

Comment: Me it gives me an error,
Here is my code:
`window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory+'Music/', function (fileSystem) {
        var reader = fileSystem.createReader();
        reader.readEntries( function (entries) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Entry: '+entries, null, 'RedSet', 'OK');
        }, function (err) {
            navigator.notification.alert('Err! '+err, null, 'RedSet', 'OK');
        });
    }, function (err) {
        navigator.notification.alert('Error! '+err, null, 'RedSet', 'OK');
    });`